# Transferring Whatsapp history from person to person

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

I deleted my Whatsapp history with person X, but the conversation history still exists on X's phone. So can I get back the history from the X's phone?

Comment: You could have written this to the WhatsApp developers. I think nobody here has an idea about this.